# GTM: Click Element Trigger not firing

Tags: google-analytics, triggers, google-tag-manager

I can't understand why my triger is not firing.
[image: Click Element Trigger]

Does anyone know how to fix it?
I have couple elements on pages that contains `span.sharing__icon` in Click Element so I want to use single trigger for all of them.

Here's the screen on my setup in GTM:
[image: gtm trigger settings]

Thanks to everyone in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elements don't "start with".
Elements match css selectors.

Change your condition to be a match rather than starts with.

Answer (score 0):

Try  giving the click element a class ID in the source code, and use the condition for **Click Classes** that equals that Class name you assigned for that click element.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, as mentioned use matches CSS selector and you can click on copy selector when using inspect element. (Make sure to copy the selector on the URL element)

[image: matches css selector]